# Binding TextBlock to C# code using Source = {Binding} not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-store-apps

At the very simplest level all I am trying to do is Data Bind TextBlock control (XAML). Am tying to get string from  MyString (property defined in C# code behind) as a Text for TextBlock:

```
DisplayText disp = new DisplayText();
disp.MyString = "Hello";

 public class DisplayText {
       public string MyString {get;set;}
       }
```

XAML code:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=MyString}" Foreground="Black"/>
```

But, Its not working:( Am searching for hours but could'nt get this simple thing done. Plz help!

Answer (score 0):

In your XAML you need to define the DataContext.

For example:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Also, you'll need to implement [INotifyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if you want the screen and model to stay in sync.

Comment: Yup ... I included DataContext. Problem is only when I declare MyString as a member variable of Main class it works. But when its declared as variable of separate class (class DisplayText as in my case here), and initialize it, it do not get bind. Can you tell why??

Comment: DataContext should be the instance of `disp`, since that's what you are trying to bind to, not Self. If you create disp in code behind, it makes sense to define DataContext there as well, e.g. right after InitializeComponents() call you put `DataContext = disp;`. And yes, if you want to set `MyString` value _after_ DataContext is assigned, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged becomes really important.

Comment: Just keep in mind that binding can be as flexible as you want. E.g. if you like the idea of feeding DataContext from Self, you can have `Disp` exposed as a property in there - what you call a Main class - and bind TextBlock property like this: `Text="{Binding Disp.MyString}"`

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the msdn article about data binding in Store Apps? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464965.aspx

The example code shows how to do what you are describing and worked for me.